# ELIF is not returning

Tags: python-3.x

import difflib
import json
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
from difflib import get_close_matches

```
data=json.load(open("data.json"))
#word= input("enter a word:")

def tranlate(word):
    word = word.lower()

if word in data:
    return data[word]
elif len(get_close_matches(word,data.keys()))> 0 :
    x=get_close_matches(word,data.keys())[0]
       
    z = input("do u mean %s instead?Enter Y if yes or N if no" %x)
    if z.lower() ==  "y" or "yes":
        return data[x]
    elif z.lower()== "n" or "no":
        return "please enter correct word"
    else:
        return "we do not understand your entry"
else:
        
        
    return "this word does not exixt,please double check it"
#ratio = SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()

word= input("enter a word:")
print(tranlate(word))
```

this below code are not running and it keeps executing

```
if z.lower() ==  "y" or "yes":
            return data[x]
elif z.lower()== "n" or "no":
            return "please enter correct word"
        else:
            return "we do not understand your entry"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` condition is incorrect :

It should be written as :

```
if z.lower() ==  "y" or z.lower()== "yes":
            return data[x]
elif z.lower()== "n" or z.lower()== "no":
            return "please enter correct word"
else:
            return "we do not understand your entry"
```

Originally, you are doing :  `z.lower() ==  "y" or "yes"`

this leads to : `"y" or "yes"`, which always return true, and hence it will never go to the other conditions.